# Prevent a project from building if a dependent project fails

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

I have a VS2010 solution that includes a custom project. The project builds an installer out of all the libraries and executables built in the same solution. This is a third-party installer builder, not a native Visual Studio installer project. It runs a custom command in the post-build event of the project.

The problem with this setup is that the installer project build runs (and succeeds!) even if some other project build fails.

I have added *project dependencies* so that the installer project depends on all other projects, to no avail. I have also tried to add *project references* with the same result.

This happens only with this specific project (probably because it's a custom project with configuration type "utility"). Other projects don't start building if a dependent project fails to build.

This is a dangerous situation. A developer may not pay attention to a build failure in some other project and use the incorrectly built installer. I need MSVC to skip building the installer project if some other project fails.

How should I deal with it?

Ideally this should be solved at the MSVC level. I don't want to add custom checks to the installer build command because this would mean I have to maintain a list of projects/targets in two separate places. I also don't want to introduce additional tools to the picture.

Comment: Don't get too attached to installer projects, the feature was removed from VS 5 years ago.  Not because they worked that well.  In general there should be a reasonable expectation that they are only configured to build in a Release build, that the Release build is trouble-free because the Debug build was thoroughly tested and that the person that signs the installer makes a minimal effort to check that the installer works.  Doesn't have to be more complicated than that.

Comment: @HansPassant This is a project that runs a custom installer builder built around a third party product, not a native VS installer project. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @HansPassant A project with a working debug build and a failing release build it is also not so uncommon as we want. In such cases the installer works and the product also immediately appears to work, but fails afterwards because of a missing file.